# What do you say when giving something to somebody?

Tags: spoken-language, phrase-requests, giving-and-receiving

In English when you hold out something to someone, sometimes a vocal prompt like "here" or "there" is said to indicate that you are giving it to the person.

In Chinese (or at least in Singapore) we sometimes use something that sounds like "na" or even use the Chinese word "给(gěi)" as an expression while holding out something towards the recipient.

EDIT: Perhaps I should have been more specific about what I'm referring to. I'm not referring to giving "gifts", but just giving in general. Something like just passing a note to somebody or when someone looks in need of a tissue and you just hold it out to them.

**(Question)** What's the equivalent of this concept in Japanese? I ask because I think it feels quite awkward to either remain silent, or to form a complete sentence asking the person to receive it especially if you are familiar with the person.

Comment: I say はい、どうぞ and I'm curious to see the answers to your question.

Comment: I do not know what the tag [single-word-requests] means.  Does that mean that “はい、どうぞ” is not an answer you are looking for?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I included both "single-word" and "phrase" requests because I didn't want to limit the answer to either of them.

Comment: Related to this - I keep wanting to say どうぞ when giving money to cashiers, but my friends tell me that is strange (because I am under obligation to do so). And I feel uncomfortable saying nothing. Might be my cultural conditioning. What is appropriate in that situation?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: There's a tag in the English SE for "single-word-requests": http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Did you mean "knew", rather than "know"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Tsuyoshi was asking regarding my choice of including the tag, and not about the tag itself. And your nitpickery of tense in know/knew is irrelevant and may be considered accusatory. Pls reconsider your words.

Comment: @Flaw: I wasn't meaning to nitpick - I wasn't sure whether Tsuyoshi meant "Thanks, but I already knew that", or "Thanks, I now understand". Also, I would prefer that you didn't use txt-speak when replying to me - please use "please" rather than "pls". Nothing against you - I just really dislike txt-speak.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Fair enough. Noted.

Comment: @Amadan How about using はい *(if anything...)*? ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`はい`

`どうぞ`

`これ、あげます`

`小さいものですが…`

`よけいなものなんですが…`

Comment: `小さいものですが` is strange. Rather, `つまらないものですが` is common.

Comment: よけいなものなんですが also sounds unusual.

Comment: It's probably worth clarifying that `つまらないものですが` would be used in situations like giving a gift, not when simply handing a note to someone.

Comment: I think ほら can be used as well, only in informal situation though.

Answer (score 3):

In dramas and anime I often see people just saying これ

Comment: Or a simple variation like はい、これ！